# Rename Android Package - Google Play upload Error

Tags: android, package, rename

I tried to upload my apk to Google Play, and I got this error:

`You need to use a different package name because "com.example" is restricted.`

I use Eclipse, how do I rename the package?
I tried rename:
`src\com.example.xyz` to `com.xyz` using `refactor`, but I got error in all my .java files which pointed to the R.java file. What else does need to be renamed to get rid of this error? Do I need to rename something inside `gen\`?

Comment: rename the package in the manifest

Comment: You could do this : right click project->Android tools->rename application package name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay as `tyczj` stated:

I also need to rename package inside manifest (along with renaming `src\com...`).

Thank you